# interest rate volatility modeling

Tags: time-series, stata, garch

I need to model interest rate volatility with GARCH(1,1) by using $IR_t = c + IR_{-1} +e_t$ as the mean equation. In other words, I should obtain the conditional variance using $IR_t = c + IR_{-1} + e_t$ where $c$ is constant and $e$ is error term.
$IR$ stands for interest rate.

How can I exercise this process? Actually, I am confused with the mean equation and how to specify it in Stata or in the others.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a GARCH model can be written as:
\begin{align}
r_t&=\mu_t+\epsilon_t \\
\epsilon_t &=\sigma_t z_t \, ,z_t \overset{iid}{\sim}(0,1)
\end{align}
Where $\mu_t=E(r_t\vert {\cal F}_{t-1})$ is the expected value of $r_t$ given the information set ${\cal F}_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_t$ is the error term. $\mu_t$ is often called the mean equation, since dynamics in the mean of the time series are modeled by $\mu_t$. Dependence in the second moments are modeled by using the variance equation, i.e. the functional form of $\sigma_t^2$ since $Var(r_t \vert {\cal F}_{t-1})=\sigma_t^2$.

Depending on the functional form of $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t^2$ and also the distribution assumption for $z_t$, you get a different model. However, your mean equation is known and you want to use a GARCH(1,1)-model for the variance equation, so you have the model:
\begin{align}
IR_t&=c+IR_{t-1}+\epsilon_t \\
\epsilon_t&=\sigma_t z_t \\
\sigma_t^2&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2
\end{align}
So the only thing you need to specify in this case is the distribution of $z_t$. Standard assumptions are the standard normal distribution or standardized t- distribution. Now you can estimate your model via ML.

A quick example using rugarch package in R:

```
library(rugarch)
#Specify GARCH(1,1)-model with normal innovations
Model<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = sGARCH, garchOrder = c(1,1)),  
                  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,0), include.mean = TRUE, 
                  archm =FALSE), distribution.model = "norm",
                  fixed.pars = list(ar1 = 1))


#Estimate model, I assume IR is the vector of interest rates
Model_Fit<-ugarchfit(spec = Model, data = IR, solver = "hybrid")
```

Comment: I am very thankful for the answer, but it says that the mean equation  is "IRt=c+IR−1+et", not IR(t-1), (I dont know how can I write them as subindexes) in the paper. This is where I am confused actually, is it possible to construct that mean equation to obtain the conditional variance? or there might be a typo?

Comment: @user31603 If you literally mean $IR_{-1}$ (which seems unusual to me but obviously didn't read the paper), then that's a constant which can be absorbed into the other one like $IR_t = c' + e_t$.

Comment: @Jonas_Dim The call to `ugarchspec` isn't right because the coefficient in front of $IR_{t-1}$ isn't actually free (it's 1).

Comment: @ChrisHaug nice comment, I corrected my answer by setting ar1 equal to 1.

Comment: @user31603 can you give a reference of the paper? I am confused what $IR_{-1}$ means. My current answer is valid for $IR_{t-1}=IR_{-1}$. However, if you mean $IR_t=c+IR-1+\epsilon_t=c'+\epsilon_t$, simply delete "armaOrder=c(1,0)" and "fixed.pars=list(ar1=1)" in the code above and you should be fine.

Comment: yeah the paper says this and this is what I thought but I am not sure though @ChrisHaug.  The link for the paper : http://repositorio.ipea.gov.br/bitstream/11058/6576/1/ppp_n46_the_importance.pdf
page 22 5th footnote

Comment: @Jonas_Dim http://repositorio.ipea.gov.br/bitstream/11058/6576/1/ppp_n46_the_importance.pdf page 22 footnote 5, thanks

Comment: The authors seem to use notation $X_{(-1)}$ to refer to the lagged-one version of process $X$ (with time index suppressed); see table 4 and corresponding equation 10. In that particular footnote, they have mixed up the two notations, and they most likely mean $IR_t = c + IR_{t-1} + e_t$.

Comment: thank you so much I was very confused with the notation @ChrisHaug

Comment: @user31603 in this case you can estimate the model by using the code provided in the answer.